# Grouping using LINQ

Tags: .net, sql, xml, vb.net, linq

I'm having a heck of a time with transforming a simple SQL Query into a LINQ query(using vb btw)

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT     USRDEFND5
FROM         int_gp_employee
GROUP BY USRDEFND5
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<int_gp_employee>
  <row>
    ....
    <usrdefnd5>Some GUID</usrdefnd5>
  </row>
</int_gp_employee>
```

I've tried a number of different variations of the LINQ.  My current statement is:

`From b In xmlFile...<row> Group b...<usrdefnd5> By b...<usrdefnd5> INTO group`

when I foreach through the resulting collection, EVERY line (17000) shows up.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I don't know the VB equivalent for sure, but in C# this would be:

```
var query = from row in xmlFile.Descendants("row")
            group row by (string) row.Element("usrdefnd5");
```

Without using XML literals, the VB would be:

```
Dim query = From row In document.Descendants("row") _
            Group row By CStr(row.Element("usrdefnd5"))
```

EDIT: If you just need the distinct keys, then something like:

```
Dim query = From row In document.Descendants("row") _
            Select CStr(row.Element("usrdefnd5")) _
            Distinct
```

Comment: Still returns all of them.  I'm looking for distinct values of usrdefnd5.

Comment: It should be returning all the rows, but grouped by that field. Each group will be a sequence of rows with that key. Do you need the rows at all, or *just* the keys?

Comment: I should say, I just need the DISTINCT keys.

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work:

[code]
Dim xmlFile As XDocument = XDocument.Load("h:\test\xml\int_gp_employee.xml")
dim branch_ids = From row IN xmlFile...<row> SELECT row...<USRDEFND5> Distinct

for each b in branch_ids
 console.writeline(b.value)
next [/code]

Sorry, I don't know how to mark up the comments section yet.